# how to add new element to the existing node in xml 

Tags: iphone

i have an xml file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imageset>
<category>
<image>SQUIRREL</image>
<image>FOX</image>  
<image>TIGER</image>    
<image>LION</image> 
</category>
</imageset>
```

Now i need to add another elemnt to the parent node imageset like this.
eg: i need to add `<image>DOG</image>`

SQUIRREL
    FOX
    TIGER
    LION
    **DOG**

i know that to get elements by node wise we need to use xml parse.

But i don't know to write element to the same xml file.

How can i done can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: I don't think people why down vote my question with out comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on iPhone you can use either a SAX parser called The "NSXMLParser" class
or you can use a DOM parser Like NSXML for this one You want to use DOM Like NSXML since you want to edit the file. On iPhone they Took NSXMLDocument out due to it being too resource intensive. Use something like either "Kiss XML" or "Touch Base XML".
If you are not familier with parsing XML its really simple and easy I suggest since you are on the iPhone use the ADC Documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html

Its a great tutorial!

Comment: How can i write using nsxml parser